# How do you remove a point?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4, point

How do i remove a point? I have searched all over the web, however i can not find a solution...
My code in simple terms:

Creating variables:

```
    var point1:Point=new Point();
    var point2:Point=new Point();
    var bullet:MovieClip=new bullet;
    var box:MovieClip=new box;
```

Setting the position of the box and point

```
    box.x=200;
    box.y=200;

    point2.x=200;
    point2.y=200;
```

Setting the speed of the bullet:

```
    bullet.speedX=10;
```

Adding a listener to the stage:

```
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, inToFrame)
    function inToFrame (evt:Event)
    {
        bullet.x+=bullet.speedX;
        point1.x=bullet.x;
        point1.y=bullet.y;
        if(Point.distance(point1,point2)<10)
        {
            if(this.contains(bullet))
                {
                    removeChild(bullet);
                    //And here I want one of the two points to be removed
                }
            if(this.contains(box))
                {
                    removeChild(box);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Point class cannot be placed on the stage ( http://help.adobe.com/en_EN/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html , not DisplayObject). It's just abstract structure. There's no points on stage! So, what do you want to remove in real?

Comment: Thanks @Smolniy, I just do not want the point to interact with the other point the next time they are within a radius of 10 from each other.

Comment: But I got my answer, thank you @Pier ! :)

Answer (score 4):

They are not even on the stage, `Point` is not a display object it can't be added to stage.

**Edit** just set `point1` back to an initial position like 0,0 so it doesn't go into the if statement on the next check. Or better just check if bullet is on stage before checking the distance between the two points

```
if(bullet.parent && Point.distance(point1,point2)<10)
{
     if(this.contains(bullet))
     {
         removeChild(bullet);
         //And here I want one of the two points to be removed
     }
     if(this.contains(box))
     {
         removeChild(box);
     }
}
```

Comment: I see, still it does not solve my problem. The basic concept is that a bullet, which is bearing with it a point i fired towards an object, which is also bearing with it a point. And when the two points come within a certain radius of each other, both the object and the point is to be destroyed. I can only destroy the object, which is a movie clip.

Comment: it doesn't solve your problem because the code you showed is not enough to determine  what you need done

Comment: Like @Daniel said you didn't show the code that adds a bullet to the stage, you don't want to remove points you want to remove bullets from the stage. If you have a `bullet` then just do `stage.removeChild(bullet);` in the if statement

Comment: Ok, now I have updated the code. My problem is not that I can not remove the child, but when I do the point remains, so if i fire a new bullet it disappears when it is to close to the remaining point